# How to find the consumer of dynamodb stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

In AWS console, how can I find the consumer(Eg. SQS, Lambda, Kinesis, etc.) of the dynamodb stream. I have the name of the dynamodb table and they have dynamodb stream enabled. But from this dynamodb page, how can I find which all consumers are using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, when the streams are enabled for a DynamoDB table you can get data from a stream with

- AWS CLI ([`aws dynamodbstreams get-records`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodbstreams/get-records.html))
- AWS REST API ([`GetRecords`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_GetRecords.html))
- AWS SDK (e.g. [Java SDK 1.x](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBStreams.html#getRecords-com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.GetRecordsRequest-), [Java SDK 2.x](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/streams/DynamoDbStreamsClient.html#getRecords-software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.GetRecordsRequest-))
- [DynamoDB Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Basically, you can only find the triggers (consumers) for a particular DynamoDB table on a corresponding tab.
This tabs lists all the Lambdas that consume records from a table stream (i.e. triggers):

[image: "Triggers" tabs]

You cannot just list those consumers who use CLI, REST or SDK.
You could probably use [AWS Cloudtrail to track DynamoDB activity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/logging-using-cloudtrail.html), but it does not seem to track `GetRecords` or `GetItem`.